# Reputation of migrated question was not deleted from the original site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, migration, migrated-questions

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, which was migrated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450575/android-how-to-force-browsers-not-to-reload-recently-seen-page-after-resume
But before the migration I got 2 downvotes, which I still have in Stack Overflow. I think that should be deleted or migrated as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downvotes do not follow a migration, that's by design and the reasoning is that your question is starting a new life on a new site. Upvotes on the other hand do follow the migration, and the reasoning for this, I'm guessing, is that we are just that nice.

The downvoted & closed version of your question will be deleted eventually, when that happens you will get back your reputation (again, we are *that* nice ;).

Comment: I can see my question at my SO summary page, but when I click on, it is opened on the new site. So does that mean the question still exist?

Comment: @laplasz There are currently two versions of your question, one on SO and one on Android Enthusiasts. However, people visiting the SO version of your question will be automatically redirected to Android Enthusiasts, unless they add `?noredirect=1` at the [end of the url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450575/android-how-to-force-browsers-not-to-reload-recently-seen-page-after-resume?noredirect=1). The SO version still exists, but it will be deleted at some point, either automatically after a month or earlier by the community.

Comment: @laplasz The reason we keep both versions around for a while is that not all migrations are correct, there's always a chance a question was migrated to another site incorrectly and we need to bring it back.

Comment: So maybe for new users it is a little bit confusing. so when I click on the question at SO summary site it should be called with ?noredirect=1. What do you think?