# migrated question should be linked with ?noredirect=1 on the profile page of the orig site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, migration

It can be confusing for beginners whose question was migrated to another site.

The question can also be found on the profile page of the original site for a while, but when the question is visited from there - the browser is redirected to the site that the question was migrated to. So the user thinks that the question is already removed from the original site. But it isn't yet.

Answer (score 8):

This is by design.

When clicking on the link to the question on the original site you are take to the new site - so you can edit the question, check out any answers etc.

If you want to go back to the original question click on the "Migrated from" link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I think this is a faulty design then... because from the orig site user  would like to open the orig question - and if he/she wants to see the migrated site can navigate from there. for me this is obvious

Comment: @laplasz can you explain ***why*** they need to be able to open the original question (which is going to get deleted)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand can you expalin **why** the system keeps the migrated question on the orig site? if it is effectively removed? my opinion is that till it is not removed and listed on the orig site I would like to see the orig message...

Comment: @laplasz Anna explained that - the migration might be rejected.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I agree with that. But what sence listing the question on the summary at the orig site if I cannot navigate to it directly? Migrated question should be marked with some icon to indicate the fact - but if you would like to open it  - system should let the user to open the orig site...

Comment: @AaronBertrand otherwise user might think that the question has already removed and asking question like this: [Reputation of migrated question was not deleted from the original site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148144/reputation-of-migrated-question-was-not-deleted-from-the-original-site)

Comment: @laplasz people who don't understand the system are going to ask those questions. I think the change you propose will result in a lot more problems than the occasional question about down-votes when automatically guiding the user to the new location. And I don't know how opening the original question will prevent those questions anyway.

Comment: @AaronBertrand maybe now I know what is confusing at least for me: migrated questions in the list is not marked at all with the fact, that it is migrated - even the title of the question is the very origin in the list, although it has changed at new site - so if the link points to the new question, then the title of the question should follow the changes as well

Comment: @AaronBertrand so If I could see which questions has migrated just looking the list - maybe I wouldnt klick on it - since it has migrated - so an icon needed next to the question  - migrated or not - and with this additional info you want to see the question then you will not suprise if you see your old question where you can navigate to the new site - for me that would be obvious

Comment: @laplasz Migrated questions show up with "[migrated]" at the end. That might not be visible from the profile summary cause there isn't always enough horizontal space to fit the whole question title, but migrated questions are definitely denoted as such.

Comment: @AnnaLear if I go abow my question with my mouse, the tag, or tooltip doest not show the [migrated], additionaly - I opended the site on 1600X1020 but the summary page is limited to some 1024 or around that - so this [migrated] sign/mark is useless on summary page

Answer (score 2):

Why does it matter that their original question is still temporarily on the original site? They should be focusing their efforts on the question in its new location, which has been determined to be the proper location for the question.

Comment: yes - but user knows that the question was migrated because it apperas at the new site as well - and if it is not obvious then visiting the question itself tells the user that it is migrated - so following this mathod user will know that this question hasnt removed yet, but it has migrated, and not asking this question: [Reputation of migrated question was not deleted from the original site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148144/reputation-of-migrated-question-was-not-deleted-from-the-original-site)

Comment: @laplasz Still don't understand why the user needs to know that the original question is still there, or why they would ever need to navigate to it. You're doing a lot of hand-waving but I don't see a real reason embedded anywhere in your comments.

Answer (score 2):

It's *effectively* removed from the original site: it's closed, locked, and any existing answers have been moved to the new location.

The stub left behind will be automatically deleted after a while (just to make sure the migration isn't rejected by the destination site). There's basically no reason to ever look at that original version again.

If anything, sending someone new to the site there will be more confusing since they'll never see any new answers or possibly know to click on the "migrated to" link.

Comment: for me whos is quite new on this site It was clear what should be done to visit the new site - because the only action I can make on a migrated question is the navigation to the new site. But I hanvet noticed that I can go back to the original site from the migrated site, because there are lot of actions

Comment: I do have a reason to look at the original version sometimes: I want to see the comments that were left before the migration. In particular, comments that state “this should be on [site name](link)”, which get deleted in the migration process. The “Return to Question” link at the top of the revision history for a migrated question should have `?noredirect=1`.